# PHP preg_match() for non English letters

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-match

I'm trying to do some function in PHP using preg_match() to check if variable contains some words.

```
if(preg_match('#\b(hello|hi)\b#', $_POST['text']))
    {   
        echo "Hi.";
    }
```

This code forks fine, but when I'm trying to write non English letters like "გამარჯობა" it doesn't work.
What's the problem?

Comment: English, or Latin?

Comment: Yes, sorry I mean Latin

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved!